# Multiple rounded corners on view

Tags: ios, swift, layout

I have a view which I want to set multiple rounded corners on. It´s a normal squared `UIView`.

And I´m calling this function which is an extension:

```
func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = mask
}
```

With the following:

```
myView.roundCorners(.bottomLeft, radius: 20)
myView.roundCorners(.bottomRight, radius: 20)
```

But only bottomRight is rounded, any clues why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UIRectCorner` parameter is a struct that conforms to optionSet protocol which allows you to pass multiple members of the set. Each time you call that method with a different `roundCorners` mask it will override the previous layout.

You need to do this if you want multiple rounded corners for your view:

```
myView.roundCorners([.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Rashwan L said above UIRectCorner takes an array of options.
What happened when you really called the method the mask is overrided. 
Also in the method after setting the mask
`self.layer.maskToBounds = true`
and before modifying self call:
 `self.layoutIfNeeded()`
It prepares your views to be drawn correctly.